# Wordpress page not found on AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I have transferred a wordpress website on AWS (EC2 and RDS-Mysql servers). The DNS has been setup in Route53.

The wordpress files has been located under directory:

```
/var/www/html
```

And the mysql database is imported on RDS. The home page looks fine but when I click on the other pages, it gives "404 not found" error. I have modified /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file to allow WordPress to use permalinks:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
AllowOverride All
```

I have also checked the size of transferred files and they look as same as the main files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem by adding .htaccess file in the directory of my wordpress files.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

http://guiem.info/permalinks-on-wordpress-amazon-ec2/

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow these steps:

1. In the WordPress dashboard go to Settings > Permalinks
2. Without changing anything click on the Save button

And then try to click on the inner pages, it should load fine.

Why does this happen? When you change server, the paths and urls are changed. When you save permalink settings then WordPress will update its rewrite rules and so it will work fine.